# Filter through a table

Tags: javascript

I ran into an issue in using a search bar to filter through table.

I don't seem to be able to get the function to filter through the tbody section of this table.

The tbody information is printed through JS using innerHTML using the "planes" as ID

```js
function searchBar() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, j, td, txtval;
  input = document.getElementById("search")
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("planes")
  tr = table.getElementByTagName("tr")

  //loop
  for (j = 0; j < tr.length; j++) {
    td = tr[j].getElementByTagName("td")[0];
    td = tr[j].getElementByTagName("td")[1];
    td = tr[j].getElementByTagName("td")[2];
    td = tr[j].getElementByTagName("td")[3];
    td = tr[j].getElementByTagName("td")[4];
    td = tr[j].getElementByTagName("td")[5];
    td = tr[j].getElementByTagName("td")[6];
    if (td) {
      txtval = td.textContext || td.innerText;
      if (txtval.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[j].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[j].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-grid mdl-grid" style="padding-top:50px;  justify-content: center; text-align: center">

  <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Plane Registration </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Plane location </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Range (KM) </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Average Speed <br>(Knots) </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Plane Type </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Status </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Airline </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="planes">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please complete it to make a [mcve]. Add some example data and how you call the function

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues.

- getElementByTagName should be plural getElementsByTagName
- You replace the td for each assignment, but if you fixed that
- You would show when found and then immediately hide when not found in the next cell

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input", function() {
    const filter = this.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    [...document.querySelectorAll("#planes tr")].forEach(tr => {
      const found = [...tr.querySelectorAll("td")].some(td => {
        const txtval = (td.textContext || td.innerText).toUpperCase();
        return (txtval.includes(filter))
      })
      const hide = filter !== "" && !found;
      tr.classList.toggle("hide", hide);
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" />
<div class="content-grid mdl-grid" style="padding-top:50px;  justify-content: center; text-align: center">

  <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Plane Registration </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Plane location </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Range (KM) </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Average Speed <br>(Knots) </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Plane Type </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Status </th>
        <th style="text-align: center"> Airline </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="planes">
      <tr>
        <td>ONYX</td>
        <td>Texas</td>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>Cessna</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>Texas Airline</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>AAAA</td>
        <td>Heathrow</td>
        <td>30000</td>
        <td>800</td>
        <td>747</td>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>BA</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```